# $K$-algebras: intuition, and when can we give a ring the structure of a $K$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces

I am just learning about algebras (defined as unital rings as well as $K$-vector spaces with some other properties, where $K$ is a field) and I am having trouble visualizing them. First of all, I do not know when is it more convenient to look at them as we have just defined and when is it more convenient looking at them as vector spaces over a field with an inner bilinear multiplication.

I was also wondering about when can we give a unital ring the structure of a $K$-algebra. For example, I was looking at the case where we have $M$ a group, and we take the ring $(End(M), +, \circ)$. I think this will be a $K$-algebra for any field $K$. The only type of ring I think will not lead to a $K$-algebra are the ones that have some weird addition, since it has to be the same as the addition of the vector space. Are these the only cases when we cannot turn a unital ring into an algebra.

Comment: @Sverre Please make your comment a solution rather than an answer. It says pretty much everything anyone would want to say!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any $K$-algebra contains an isomorphic copy of $K$ in the center, in fact this is an alternative definition of a $K$-algebra. So for example from this you can see $\mathbb Z$ can not be given the structure of an algebra over any field. Also $\text{End}(\mathbb Z^+) \cong \mathbb Z$ as rings, which gives you an example of an endomorphism ring of an abelian group which isn't a $K$-algebra for any field $K$.